# Where to get a web graph with corresponding web pages dataset

Tags: web-development, search-engine

I'm trying to implement `PageRank` algorithm on a set of web pages, for that I need a sample `dataset` of web pages, and the web graph corresponding to them, this web graph represents the links between the pages that the data set contains.

I need the web graph so I can get the transition matrix and do the calculation needed

Example :

```
      URL1 -> URL2
      URL3390->URL5
```

and the URLxxxx as an id, is mapped somehow to the corresponding web page so I can know how to map.

My question is: how/where can I get this resource (I've tried many links on the internet but nothing really helps), I would also like it to be not of a very large size, (internet connexion limitation), if I can't have this as it is, advice me what should I do ?

Comment: [Same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23376840/1591669) on SO.